# Условие в ссылке

Tags: html

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как реализовать условие в ссылке через html. Например, есть одна страница example.html. Нужно, чтобы при открытии на странице была какая-то надпись и кнопка edit. При нажатии на эту кнопку должна открываться другая страница, даже не другая, а та же самая (должен быть только один файл), но уже на этой странице должна быть форма с полем для ввода и кнопка save, которая сохраняет текст из формы и кидает на "первую" страницу, где должен быть новый текст, который введен в форму и кнопка edit. И это нужно сделать только через условие в url, например, ya.ru/example.html?edit=true.

Comment: Добавьте мету "javascript", так как он понадобится. 

Хотя есть грязный хак: html5 атрибут [*contenteditable*](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126877/)

    <p contenteditable="true">Меня можно редактировать</p>

Comment: @Sergiks, спасибо!
Но хотелось бы через условиев url :)

Comment: Подсказка: в JavaScript свойство `window.location.search` содержит всю строку GET запроса, начиная с "?". Напр. для `site.ru/page.html` это будет пустая строка, а для `site.ru/page.html?edit` это "?edit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так, хотя это кривизна страшная:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="Ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/template" id="page1">
        <p>Это просто такая первая страница</p>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Нажми!">
        </form>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="page2">
        <p>Вторая страница, фарш и фрикадельки!</p>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Не нажимай!">
        </form>
    </script>

    <script>
        var el = document.getElementById("container");

        switch(window.location.search){
            case "?page=2":
                el.innerHTML = document.getElementById("page2").innerHTML;
                break;

            case "?page=1":
            default:
                el.innerHTML = document.getElementById("page1").innerHTML;
                break;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @Sergiks, появился вопрос: что тут делает hidden? Прочитав, понял, что это скрытое поле, которое содержит информацию, которая не видна пользователю. Но как hidden используется в этом коде?

Comment: @compl при нажатии на кнопку отправляется форма методом GET, т.е. все её поля следуют после знака вопроса:

    страница.html?поле1=значение1&поле2=значение2&..полеN=значениеN

В нашем случае это скрытое поле и несет имя "page" и значение либо 1 либо 2, что в итоге, дает `страница.html?page=1` или `страница.html?page=2`

Comment: @Sergiks, спасибо, понял.